# MSSQL WHERE LIKE using Caret I want 1 char but I dont want another one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I have problem with this statement. I want to have string with 'O' but not with 'G'.
Third line WHERE works but Is it possible to write It in a simpler way like one of others?

```
select * from 
   (select '1XGOX' as x union
    select  '2XOGX' as x union
    select  '3XO' as x union
    select  '4XG' as x) as y
where
--x like '%[O^G]%'
--x like '%[O]%[^G]%'
x like '%[O]%' and x not like '%[G]%'
```

Desired output 3XO  (There's ' O ' and no ' G ' )

Comment: So from your example what do you want as output?

Comment: You could use charindex to eliminate G but it isn't much different and the result would be the same. SQL Sever does not have full regex capability, only rough pattern matching

Comment: I removed caret and changed like - sorry. Also I added desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like matchers are **NOT** regular expressions. You can remove the character class brackets:

```
where x like '%O%' and x not like '%G%'
```

but that's as close as you'll get.

If we know more about what these codes represent, and why certain characters appear and seem to be in certain positions, we might be able to do a little better. But as is, this is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server does not support full regular expressions (although the comparison is not trivial with regular expression).  I think the two-step comparison is the simplest method.

For your examples, where the "G" is adjacent to the "O", you could do:

```
where 'O' + y.x + 'O' like '%[^G]O[^G]%'
```

The string manipulation on the left handles "O" at the beginning/end of the string.

However, I find the two comparisons to be simpler to understand -- they are pretty much a direct translation of your statemnt.

Comment: Especially if there can be characters in between the `O` and `G`.  *(Which is neither stated nor excluded by the OP.)*